# Cannot connect to any remote database after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, ssms, windows-10

After upgrading a `Windows 10`, cannot connect to any remote db in this case using `SSMS`

I have installed `TMG` client and the port are open, other developers with `Windows 7` can connect to the database, this only happens to the developers that have `Windows 10`

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: can you connect via server IP address instead of server name? Can you show an example of your connection string? are any errors showing in the event viewer of the client machine or the database server?

Comment: try to use alternative tools, like dbForge - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/

Comment: This is my connection string 
Data Source=198.71.226.2;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=******

and not error is showing in the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

From my googling, a common theme for this is that when the connection to the remote database is in the format `{Server Name}\{Instance Name}`, Windows 10 throws a fit and won't allow the connection.

Instead, try `{Server IP Address}\{Instance Name}`.